# Quick help creating a stacked bar chart (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

> `> DF`
>   `Year Metric MWh`
>   `2003 Demand   498343`
>   `2004 Demand  1250904`
>   `2005 Demand  1665176`
>   `2006 Demand  2317643`
>   `2007 Demand  2455311`
>   `2008 Demand  3557987`
>   `2009 Demand  4268125`
>   `2010 Demand  5403704`
>   `2011 Demand  6596158`
>   `2012 Demand  7814387`
>   `2013 Demand  9008863`
>   `2014 Demand 10291085`
>   `2015 Demand 11796549`
>   `2003 Actual   159677`
>   `2004 Actual   192748`
>   `2005 Actual   248844`
>   `2006 Actual   372661`
>   `2007 Actual   705656`
>   `2008 Actual   838721`
>   `2009 Actual  1188242`
>   `2010 Actual  1708979`
>   `2011 Actual        0`
>   `2012 Actual        0`
>   `2013 Actual        0`
>   `2014 Actual        0`
>   `2015 Actual        0`
>   `2003   High        0`
>   `2004   High        0`
>   `2005   High        0`
>   `2006   High        0`
>   `2007   High        0`
>   `2008   High        0`
>   `2009   High        0`
>   `2010   High        0`
>   `2011   High  3631730`
>   `2012   High  5729024`
>   `2013   High  6741785`
>   `2014   High  9342798`
>   `2015   High 11094798`
>   `2003    Low        0`
>   `2004    Low        0`
>   `2005    Low        0`
>   `2006    Low        0`
>   `2007    Low        0`
>   `2008    Low        0`
>   `2009    Low        0`
>   `2010    Low        0`
>   `2011    Low  1637220`
>   `2012    Low  1850615`
>   `2013    Low  2064011`
>   `2014    Low  2277406`
>   `2015    Low  2490801`

I want to create a very simple stacked bar chart with:
-- x-axis: Year
-- y-axis: MWh
-- 1 stack with Demand, High, Low, and Actual ('Metric'), in that order, stacked OVER one another (as opposed to on-top). So far, I've only managed to figure out how to do it with the values stacked ON TOP of each other:

> `DF$'Metric <- factor(DF$'Metric',levels=c("Demand","High","Low","Actual"))`
>
> `qplot(x=Year,data=DF,geom="bar",weight=MWh,fill=Metric)`
>   `#OR`
>   `ggplot(DF,aes(x=factor(Year),y=MWh,fill=factor(Metric))) + geom_bar(position="stack")`

Essentially, what I'm looking for is a single bar per year where the "Demand" value is the highest, and the lower values (in the order above) are stacked over. I believe I have to use a `position="fill"` somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put it. Basically, what I am trying to show is that Demand will be steadily rising, while Supply (Actual vs. projected Low growth vs. projected High growth) has been unable to meet it in a very simple, compact graphic. If this is not possible, perhaps it would be better to simply group them side-by-side?

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: I don't have time to check, but you might be looking for `position="identity"`.

Comment: @Aniko: Thanks so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!! Cheers!!  ps, how do I flag your answer with the checkmark?

Comment: You can't accept a comment. I wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure about what you really would like to plot, but from the `position="fill"` I have an impression you want to plot the relative proportions of *Metric* per year. This can be done easily via the followings.

Loading data:

```
DF <- dput(DF)
structure(list(Year = c(2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L), Metric = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Demand", 
"High", "Low", "Actual"), class = "factor"), MWh = c(498343L, 
1250904L, 1665176L, 2317643L, 2455311L, 3557987L, 4268125L, 5403704L, 
6596158L, 7814387L, 9008863L, 10291085L, 11796549L, 159677L, 
192748L, 248844L, 372661L, 705656L, 838721L, 1188242L, 1708979L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3631730L, 
5729024L, 6741785L, 9342798L, 11094798L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1637220L, 1850615L, 2064011L, 2277406L, 2490801L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Metric", "MWh"), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = "data.frame")
```

And plot the stacked bars with the same height (with percentages):

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=factor(Year),y=MWh,fill=factor(Metric))) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill")
```

[image]

I might misunderstood what you want to plot, and plotting two distinct graph in the same picture also possible with specifying grid viewports. I recommend looking at [gridextra](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/) package, especially for `arrange`.

Answer (score 4):

`position="identity"` will not move the bars at all (as opposed to the default stacking), so they will be overlayed. You have to watch out for the ordering of the factor levels though, because this way the bars can hide behind each other.

```
 ggplot(DF,aes(x=factor(Year),y=MWh,fill=factor(Metric))) + geom_bar(position="identity")
```

Comment: this works great, but what if there are lots of dates. Is there a way to better organize the date in yaxis?