# R GGplot2 Stacked Columns Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a Stacked Columns Chart in R. Sorry but I am learning thats why i need help

This is how i have the data

```
structure(list(Category = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("MLC1000", 
    "MLC1051", "MLC1648", "MLC5726"), class = "factor"), Minutes = c(2751698L, 
    2478850L, 556802L, 2892097L), Items = c(684L, 607L, 135L, 711L
    ), Visits = c(130293L, 65282L, 25484L, 81216L), Sold = c(2625L, 
    1093L, 681L, 1802L)), .Names = c("Category", "Minutes", "Items", 
    "Visits", "Sold"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)
)
```

And i want to create this graphic

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it will be helpful if you `dput()` your data frame into the question so we can recreate it easily.

Comment: Stacked bars are really difficult for folks to interpret. Is there a reason you want to use this type of visualization over others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick help creating a stacked bar chart (ggplot2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811316/quick-help-creating-a-stacked-bar-chart-ggplot2)

Comment: @gregmacfarlane its not the same, its simillar but not the same, look how i have the data, and compare

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but here's one that is very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328134/stacked-bar-chart-in-r-using-ggplot2?rq=1

Comment: Its the same intuition....besides we cant compare it to your data bc your code has errors generating the data...

Comment: You have percentages in your picture, so they need to be calculated first. What does 100% mean in your data?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two pretty basic principles that you should apply to make this problem easier to handle. First, you should make your data [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). Second, you shouldn't leave ggplot to do your calculations for you.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- data_frame(
  category = letters[1:4],
  minutes = c(2751698, 2478850, 556802, 2892097),
  visits = c(130293, 65282, 25484, 81216),
  sold = c(2625, 1093, 681, 1802)
) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -category) %>%   # make tidy
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(weight = value / sum(value))   # calculate weight variable

## Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
## Groups: variable [3]
##   category variable   value     weight
##       <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1         a  minutes 2751698 0.31703610
## 2         b  minutes 2478850 0.28559999
## 3         c  minutes  556802 0.06415178
## 4         d  minutes 2892097 0.33321213
## 5         a   visits  130293 0.43104127
## 6         b   visits   65282 0.21596890
## 7         c   visits   25484 0.08430734
## 8         d   visits   81216 0.26868249
## 9         a     sold    2625 0.42331882
## 10        b     sold    1093 0.17626189
## 11        c     sold     681 0.10982100
## 12        d     sold    1802 0.29059829
```

I don't know what was up with your `structure()`, but I couldn't build a data frame from it without crashing my R session.

Once we get the data into this format, the `ggplot2` call is actually really easy:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = variable, weight = weight * 100, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: `library(tidyverse)`?  Is that really a thing?